# Problem with setInterval to call function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a simple script to work, but somewhere I must have done something wrong because it's not working! I just want to set an interval timing that call a function. Preciate some help. Perhaps not the best solution, but I'm new to this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

startInterval(); // activate timer

function startInterval() {
var t = setInterval("autoSave", 20000);
}

function autoSave() {
alert("test");
}

});
```

Comment: Also note that if you decide to pass parameters to the function `autoSave`, to create an anonymous function like so: 

`var t = setInterval(function(){ autoSave(param1, param2)},20000);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) better practice is to make t - global, otherwise it won't be accessible outside startInterval() function. But you'll need it to clear interval

i.e. declare var t; before `function startInterval();`

2) consider: `t = setInterval('autoSave()', 20000);`

Comment: Will the interval start if I just type var t=setInterval('autoSave()', 2000); after $(document).ready(function() {....

Comment: It worked when I just typed var t = setInterval(autoSave, 2000);

Answer (score 6):

Either one of these will work, but not what you have

```
// Pass the real function
function startInterval() {
  var t = setInterval(autoSave, 20000);
}

// THIS MAY NOT WORK
// eval
function startInterval() {
  var t = setInterval("autoSave()", 20000);
}
//

// Anonymous function
function startInterval() {
  var t = setInterval(function() { autoSave(); }, 20000);
}
```

Here's the reasoning: If you pass a function directly, it will call it. However, if you pass a string, it will to `eval` it when the timeout is up - which returns a function in your case, and in my second case returns the evaluated function (notice the parenthesis)

Comment: Hmmm, I had the parenthesis from the beginning and now I put them back, but it's still not working!?

Comment: Hmmmm very interesting, I think something has changed in the last few months because that second method used to work in all browsers. Anyway, the first method is better practice. Also, see my updated answer for a third option.

Answer (score 4):

Remove "", and make it a reference to the function.

```
function startInterval() {
  var t = setInterval(autoSave, 20000);
  //                  ^now you have a reference to
  //                   autoSave and setInterval knows
  //                   what to execute
}
```